# Beginners advice on structuring/best practices with Angular controllers and http requests

Tags: angularjs, structure

Now when my controllers are beginning to contain more code and http requests I am newbie-ing my code like this:

```
someApp.controller("SomeCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

    // *** Variables ****
    var someVar;

    // **** HTTP ****
    var httpSomeRequest = function () {
        $scope.busyWithHttpRequest = true;
        $scope.hideRequestError = true;

        $http.get(someUrl).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.busyWithHttpRequest = false;
                // Do success things
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.busyWithHttpRequest = false;
                $scope.hideRequestError = false;
                // Do error things
        });
    };

    // **** Functions ****
    var someFunctionNotUsedInHtml = function () {
        // Do something here
    };

    // **** Scoped Functions ****
    $scope.someFuntionUsedInHtml = function () {
       // Do something here
    };

    // **** Start ****
    $scope.busyWithHttpRequest = false;
    $scope.hideRequestError = true;

    someFunctionNotUsedInHtml();
}]);
```

Now my uncertainty about this code is:

1. I have decided to separate the scoped functions from the non-scoped. Is this correct or should just all functions be part of the scope?
2. When doing http requests I always like to show the user some bootstrap spinner that something is going on, hence the '$scope.busyWithHttpRequest'. This gives of course a lot of 'switching on/off ' code which is error prone. Is there a better way? Same holds for hideRequestError stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to 2 there are some options:

2.1 Use an Interceptor, see for example http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/displaying-a-loading-spinner.html

2.2 Instead of setting busyWithHttpRequest to false inside success & error it is better to do this inside finally.

I ended up with 2.2 because it is for me less complicated and by defining a (Resharper) template I will not make a mistake if I forget something.

I found another interesting posting (http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http) about a 1-for-all solution for http requests. I am also using Angular's Bootstrap Typeahead. This works with a promise so the above structure won't work with this. It is better to use the following construction which can be applied for all http request's:

```
$scope.httpGetListForTypeAhead = function (id) {
    $scope.busyWithHttpRequest = true;
    $scope.showRequestError = false;

    var encodedId = encodeURIComponent(id); // As a default I encode all my id's
    var someUrl = servicesBaseUrl + servicesSomeService + encodedId + servicesSomeServiceBaseParms; 
    return $http.get(someUrl)
        .then(function (response) {
            var someArrayToReturnToTypeAhead = [];

            return someArrayToReturnToTypeAhead;
        })
        .catch(function (ex) {
            // Add error to a (localstorage based) queue for example which can be send later to the server when http becomes available.
            $scope.showRequestError = true;
        })
        .finally(function () {
            $scope.busyWithHttpRequest = false;
        });
};
```